# How to access immediate activations of custom model containing a pretrained-model?

Tags: keras, output, layer, activation, pre-trained-model

I have a custom network of a Keras Xception base with added regression head:

```
pretrained_model = tf.keras.applications.Xception(input_shape=[244, 244, 3], include_top=False, weights='imagenet')

pretrained_model.trainable = True

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    pretrained_model,
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='tanh')
])
```

The model summary:

```
  Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
xception (Model)             (None, 7, 7, 2048)        20861480  
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d_3 ( (None, 2048)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 2048)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 32)                65568     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_5 (Dropout)          (None, 32)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 33        
=================================================================
Total params: 20,927,081
Trainable params: 20,872,553
Non-trainable params: 54,528
```

I want to get the last activations from the xception(model) layer.

The details of xception:

```
Model: "xception"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_4 (InputLayer)            [(None, 224, 224, 3) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)           (None, 111, 111, 32) 864         input_4[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________

...  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block14_sepconv2 (SeparableConv (None, 7, 7, 2048)   3159552     block14_sepconv1_act[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block14_sepconv2_bn (BatchNorma (None, 7, 7, 2048)   8192        block14_sepconv2[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block14_sepconv2_act (Activatio (None, 7, 7, 2048)   0           block14_sepconv2_bn[0][0]        
==================================================================================================
Total params: 20,861,480
Trainable params: 20,806,952
Non-trainable params: 54,528
```

To reference the last activation layer I have to use :

```
model.layers[0].get_layer('block14_sepconv2_act').output
```

since explicitly my 'model' does not contain the 'block14_sepconv2_act' layer.

To access activation I want to use the code below:

```
activations = tf.keras.Model(model.inputs,model.layers[0].get_layer('block14_sepconv2_act').output)
activations(sample)
```

but I get the error:

```
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_4_1:0", shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32) at layer "input_4". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

My question is how can I access the intermediate layer outputs of a pretrained model if added in this way to the custom model?